# KernelExplainer summary_plot modification

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, deep-learning, shap

I would like to use SHAP values to explain the below model:

```
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, X_train)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
```

The summary_plot actually works:

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[0], plot_type = 'bar')
```

but I would like to modify this plot using matplotlib features. In case:

```
plt = shap.summary_plot(shap_values[0], plot_type = 'bar', show=False)
```

The plot is shown, and the type of object *plt* is NoneType, and any modifications are impossible. Do You know how to fore the modification on this plot?

Comment: Please start-to-finish [reprex] beforehand

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following workaround:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import shap
from shap import Explanation, KernelExplainer, summary_plot

X, y = shap.datasets.iris(display=True)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X.values, y)
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(knn.predict_proba, X)
sv = explainer.shap_values(X)

summary_plot(sv[0])
x = plt.gcf()
print(type(x))
```

---

```
matplotlib.figure.Figure
```

Otherwise, I suggest editing the source code.

Comment: Unfortunately, using KernelExplainer has very low performance on my model; that's why I use DeepExplainer